# Does the autocorrelation function completely describe a stochastic process?

Tags: autocorrelation

Is a stochastic process completely described by its autocorrelation function?

If not, which additional properties would be needed?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

What is meant by a complete description of a stochastic process?  Well, mathematically, a stochastic process is a collection $\{X(t) \colon t \in {\mathbb T}\}$ of random variables, one for each time instant $t$ in an *index set* $\mathbb T$, where usually $\mathbb T$ is the entire real line or the positive real line, and a *complete description* means that for each integer $n \geq 1$ and $n$ time instants $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n \in \mathbb T$, we know the (joint) distributions of the $n$ random variables $X(t_1)$, $X(t_2)$, $\ldots, X(t_n)$.  This is an *enormous* amount of information:  we need to know the CDF of $X(t)$ for each time instant $t$, the (two-dimensional) joint CDF of $X(t_1)$ and $X(t_2)$ for all choices of time instants $t_1$ and $t_2$, the (three-dimensional) CDFs of $X(t_1)$, $X(t_2)$, and $X(t_3)$, etc. etc. etc.

So naturally people have looked about for simpler descriptions and more restrictive models.  One simplification occurs when the process is invariant to a change in the time origin.  What this means is that

- *All* the random variables in the process have identical CDFs: $F_{X(t_1)}(x) = F_{X(t_2)}(x)$ for all $t_1, t_2$.
- *Any two* random variables separated by some specified amount of time have the same joint CDF as *any other* pair of random variables separated by the *same* amount of time.  For example, the random variables $X(t_1)$ and $X(t_1 + \tau)$ are separated by $\tau$ seconds, as are the random variables $X(t_2)$ and $X(t_2 + \tau)$, and thus $F_{X(t_1), X(t_1 + \tau)}(x,y) = F_{X(t_2), X(t_2 + \tau)}(x,y)$
- Any *three* random variables $X(t_1)$, $X(t_1 + \tau_1)$, $X(t_1 + \tau_1 + \tau_2)$ spaced $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ apart have the same joint CDF as $X(t_2)$, $X(t_2 + \tau_1)$, $X(t_2 + \tau_1 + \tau_2)$ which as also spaced $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ apart. Equivalently, the joint CDF of $X(t_1), X(t_2), X(t_3)$ is the same as the joint CDF of $X(t_1+\tau), X(t_2+\tau), X(t_3+\tau)$
- and similarly for *all* multidimensional CDFs.

Effectively, the probabilistic descriptions of the random process do not depend on what we choose to call the origin on the time axis: shifting all time instants $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n$ by some fixed amount $\tau$ to $t_1 + \tau, t_2 + \tau, \ldots, t_n + \tau$ gives the same probabilistic description of the random variables.   This property is called *strict-sense stationarity* and a random process that enjoys this property is
called a strictly stationary random process or, more simply, a stationary random process. Be aware that in some of the statistics literature (especially the parts related to econometrics and time-series analysis), stationary processes are defined somewhat differently; in fact as what are described later in this answer as *wide-sense stationary* processes.

> Note that strict stationarity by itself does not require any particular form of CDF.  For example, it does not say that all the variables are Gaussian.

The adjective *strictly* suggests that  is possible to define a looser form of stationarity. If the $N^{\text{th}}$-order joint CDF of
$X(t_1), X(t_2), \ldots, X(t_N)$ is the same as the $N^{\text{th}}$-order joint CDF of $X(t_1+\tau), X(t_2+\tau), \ldots, X(t_N +\tau)$ for all
choices of $t_1,t_2, \ldots, t_N$ and $\tau$, then the random process
is said to be stationary to order $N$ and is referred to as a $N^{\text{th}}$-order stationary random process. Note that a
$N^{\text{th}}$-order stationary random process is also stationary
to order $n$ for each positive $n < N$. (This is because the $n^{\text{th}}$-order joint CDF is the limit of the $N^{\text{th}}$-order CDF as $N-n$ of the arguments approach $\infty$: a generalization of  $F_X(x) = \lim_{y\to\infty}F_{X,Y}(x,y)$). A strictly stationary random
process then is a random process that is stationary to all orders $N$.

If a random process is stationary to (at least) order $1$, then all the $X(t)$'s have the same distribution and so, assuming the mean exists, $E[X(t)] = \mu$ is the same for all $t$.  Similarly,
$E[(X(t))^2]$ is the same for all $t$, and is referred to as the *power* of the process.
All physical processes have *finite* power and so it is common to assume that
$E[(X(t))^2] < \infty$ in which case, and especially in the older engineering
literature, the process is called a *second-order* process. The choice
of name is unfortunate because it invites confusion with second-order
*stationarity* (cf. [this answer of mine on stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/65359/6633)), and so here we will call
a process for which $E[(X(t))^2]$ is finite for all $t$ (whether or
not $E[(X(t))^2]$ is a constant) as a *finite-power* process and avoid this confusion.
But note again that

> a first-order stationary process *need not be* a finite-power process.

Consider a random process that is stationary to order $2$. Now, since the joint distribution of $X(t_1)$ and $X(t_1 + \tau)$ is the same as the joint distribution function of $X(t_2)$ and $X(t_2 + \tau)$, $E[X(t_1)X(t_1 + \tau)] = E[X(t_2)X(t_2 + \tau)]$ and the value depends only on $\tau$.  These expectations are finite
for a finite-power process and their value is called the autocorrelation function of the process: $R_X(\tau) = E[X(t)X(t+\tau)]$ is a function of $\tau$, the time separation of the random variables $X(t)$ and $X(t+\tau)$, and does not depend on $t$ at all.  Note also that
$$E[X(t)X(t+\tau)] = E[X(t+\tau)X(t)] = E[X(t+\tau)X(t + \tau - \tau)] = R_X(-\tau),$$ and so
the autocorrelation function is an even function of its argument.

> A finite-power *second-order stationary* random process has the properties that

1. Its mean $E[X(t)]$ is a constant
2. Its autocorrelation function $R_X(\tau) = E[X(t)X(t+\tau)]$ is a function of $\tau$, the time separation of the random variables $X(t)$ and $X(t+\tau)$, and does not depend on $t$ at all.

---

The assumption of stationarity simplifies the description of a random process to some extent but, for engineers and statisticians interested in building models from experimental data, estimating all those CDFs is a nontrivial task, particularly when there is only a segment of one sample path (or realization) $x(t)$ on which measurements can be made. Two measurements
that are relatively easy to make (because the engineer already has the necessary instruments on his workbench (or programs in MATLAB/Python/Octave/C++ in his software library) are the *DC value*
$\frac 1T\int_0^T x(t)\,\mathrm dt$ of $x(t)$ and the autocorrelation function $R_x(\tau) = \frac 1T\int_0^T x(t)x(t+\tau)\,\mathrm dt$ (or its Fourier transform, the power spectrum of $x(t)$). Taking these measurements as *estimates* of the mean and the autocorrelation function of a finite-power
process leads to a very useful model that we discuss next.

---

> A finite-power random process is called a *wide-sense-stationary* (WSS) process (also *weakly* stationary stochastic process which fortunately also
> has the same initialism WSS) if it has a constant mean and its autocorrelation function $R_X(t_1, t_2) = E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]$ depends only on the time difference $t_1 - t_2$  (or $t_2 - t_1$).

Note that the definition says *nothing* about the CDFs of the random
variables comprising the process; it is entirely a constraint on the
first-order and second-order *moments* of the random variables. Of course, a finite-power second-order stationary (or $N^{\text{th}}$-order stationary (for $N>2$) or strictly stationary) random process *is*
a WSS process, but the converse need not be true.

> A WSS process need not be stationary to any order.

Consider, for example, the random process
$\{X(t)\colon X(t)= \cos (t + \Theta), -\infty < t < \infty\}$
where $\Theta$ takes on four equally likely values $0, \pi/2, \pi$ and $3\pi/2$. (Do not be scared: the four possible sample paths of this random process are just the four signal waveforms of a QPSK signal).
Note that each $X(t)$ is a *discrete* random variable that, in general, takes on four equally likely values $\cos(t), \cos(t+\pi/2)=-\sin(t), \cos(t+\pi) = -\cos(t)$ and $\cos(t+3\pi/2)=\sin(t)$,  It is easy to see that in general $X(t)$ and $X(s)$ have different distributions, and so the process is not even first-order stationary. On the other hand,
$$E[X(t)] = \frac 14\cos(t)+
\frac 14(-\sin(t)) + \frac 14(-\cos(t))+\frac 14 \sin(t)  = 0$$ for every $t$ while
\begin{align}
E[X(t)X(s)]&= \left.\left.\frac 14\right[\cos(t)\cos(s) +  (-\cos(t))(-\cos(s)) + \sin(t)\sin(s) + (-\sin(t))(-\sin(s))\right]\\
&= \left.\left.\frac 12\right[\cos(t)\cos(s) + \sin(t)\sin(s)\right]\\
&= \frac 12 \cos(t-s).
\end{align}
In short, the process has zero mean and its autocorrelation function depends only on the time difference $t-s$, and so the process *is* wide sense stationary. But it is not first-order stationary and so cannot be
stationary to higher orders either.

Even for WSS processes that *are* second-order stationary (or strictly stationary) random processes, little can be
said about the specific forms of the *distributions* of the random variables.  In short,

> A WSS process is not necessarily stationary (to any order), and the mean and autocorrelation function of
> a WSS process is *not enough* to give a complete statistical description
> of the process.

WSS processes are a *subclass* of what are called *covariance-stationary* random processes. Covariance-stationary processes have the property that the _covariance function of the process,
\begin{align}C_X(t_1,t_2) &= \operatorname{cov}(X(t_1), X(t_2))\\
&= E[(X(t_1)-\mu_X(t_1))(X(t_2)-\mu_X(t_2))]\\
&=E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]-\mu_X(t_1)\mu_X(t_2),\end{align} is a function only of $t_1-t_2$ and not of the individual values of $t_1$ and $t_2$. (Notice the absence of any claim that the mean is a constant). Since for a WSS process, $$C_X(t_1,t_2) = R_X(t_1,t_2)-\mu_X(t_1)\mu_X(t_2)=R_X(t_1-t_2)-\mu_X^2$$
is a function only of $t_1-t_2$, we see that every WSS process is a covariance-stationary process. In fact, the prototypical covariance-stationary process is of the form
$$\{X(t) \colon t \in {\mathbb T}\} = \{Y(t) + s(t)\colon t \in {\mathbb T}\}$$
where $\{Y(t)\colon t \in {\mathbb T}\}$ is a *zero-mean* WSS process. It is a model for a deterministic signal $s(t)$ observed in the noise $Y(t)$.
The verification of the claim that the prototypical process is indeed a covariance-stationary process is left as an exercise for the reader.

---

Finally, suppose that a stochastic process is **assumed** to be a *Gaussian* process ("proving" this with any reasonable degree of confidence is not a trivial task).
This means that for each $t$, $X(t)$ is a Gaussian random variable and for all positive integers $n \geq 2$ and choices of $n$ time instants $t_1$, $t_2$, $\ldots, t_n$, the $N$
random variables $X(t_1)$, $X(t_2)$, $\ldots, X(t_n)$ are *jointly Gaussian* random
variables.  Now a joint Gaussian density function is *completely* determined by the means $E[X(t_i)]= \mu_X(t_i)$, variances
\begin{align}\operatorname{var}(X(t_i)) &= E[(X(t_i)-\mu_X(t_i))^2]\\
&= E[(X(t_i)^2]-(\mu_X(t_i))^2\\&= R_X(t_i,t_i)-(\mu_X(t_i))^2,\end{align} and covariances
\begin{align}\operatorname{cov}(X(t_i),X(t_j)) &= E[(X(t_i)-\mu_X(t_i)])(X(t_j)-\mu_X(t_j))]\\&= E[X(t_i)X(t_j)]-\mu_X(t_i)\mu_X(t_j)\\
&=R_X(t_i,t_j)-\mu_X(t_i)\mu_X(t_j)\end{align}
of the random variables. Thus, knowing the mean function $\mu_X(t) = E[X(t)]$ (it need not be a constant as is required for wide-sense-stationarity) and the autocorrelation function $R_X(t_1, t_2) = E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]$ for all $t_1, t_2$ (it need not depend only on $t_1-t_2$ as is required for wide-sense-stationarity) is sufficient to determine the statistics of the process completely.

If a Gaussian process *is* a WSS process, then
it is also a *strictly stationary* Gaussian process.  Fortunately
for engineers and signal processors, many physical noise processes
can be well-modeled as WSS Gaussian processes (and therefore strictly
stationary processes), so that experimental observation of the
autocorrelation function readily provides all the joint distributions.
Furthermore since Gaussian processes retain their Gaussian character
as they pass through linear systems, and the output autocorrelation
function is related to th input autocorrelation function as
$$R_y = h*\tilde{h}*R_X$$
so that the output statistics can also be easily determined, WSS
process in general and WSS Gaussian processes in particular are
of great importance in engineering applications.

Comment: Could you, please, comment on "White Noise" in that sense? By definition the Autocorrelation at  $ \tau = 0 $ is the variance of the random variables. Does it mean that AWGN (Additive White Gaussian Noise) has infinite variance? I ask it because usually people write $ n(t) ~ N(0, {N}_{0} / 2) $, is wrong? Should it be written $ n(t) ~ N(0, \delta(0) {N}_{0} / 2) $? Thanks.

Comment: @Drazick Please ask a separate question.

Comment: This is a fantastic mini-course in the definition of stationary processes. I've never seen anything like it--laid out so methodically and clearly. Community Wiki?

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate Excuse me for my ignorance. In the example. Why is E[X(t)]=0 for all t ? Did you assume ergodicity? How did you derive the probability density function of X(t) from the probability density function of theta to compute the expected value? E[X(t)X(s)] = E[cos(t+theta)*cos(s+theta)] right? Which steps did you take to simplify this expression and get to what you wrote? Thanks

Comment: @VMMF There is **NO** ergodicity used. $X(t)=\cos(t+\Theta)$ is a _discrete_ random variable because $\Theta$ is a discrete random variable and it takes on values $\pm\cos(t)$ and $\pm\sin(t)$ with equal probability $\frac 14$. Ergo, $E[X(t)]=0$.  $X(t)X(s)$ takes on values $\cos(t)\cos(s)$, $(-\cos(t))(-\cos(s))=\cos(t)\cos(s)$, $\sin(t)\sin(s)$ and $(-\sin(t))(-\sin(s))=\sin(t)\sin(s)$ with equal probability $\frac 14$. Hence, $E[X(t)(X(s)]=\frac 12\big(\cos(t)\cos(s)+\sin(t)\sin(s)\big) = \frac 12\cos(t-s)$. Hence,

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate I see now! You have just used the fact that theta is discrete to substitute its 4 possible values directly. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: just to add one comment to the excellent explanation above.: if the mean and variance of the process is known, then the autocorrelation function does completely describe the process in the case where the process is gaussian. that's why the gaussian assumption is often made.

Comment: @markleeds Since the variance of the process is known as part of the autocorrelation function, I think that the statement _"knowing the mean function $\mu_X(t) = E[X(t)]$ (it need not be a constant as is required for wide-sense-stationarity) and the autocorrelation function $R_X(t_1, t_2) = E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]$ for all $t_1, t_2$ (it need not depend only on $t_1-t_2$ as is required for wide-sense-stationarity) is sufficient to determine the statistics of the process completely"_ which is already there in my answer covers it all, for WSS Gaussian processes as well as non-WSS Gaussian processes.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate: I guess there could be weird cases where one knows the correlation at the different lags and not the actual variance (i.e: suppose one were just given the correlations ) but, you are right that knowing the autocorrelation function would normally imply knowing the variance. In general, if your correlation function does depend on the difference of t1 and t2, there's a pretty big problem estimation wise so that's not a very practical situation. excellent answer you gave.

Comment: This is a wonderful answer and very clear explanation.  Thank you.