# How do we compute distrubtions of the value of a random process conditional on initial conditions?

Tags: autocorrelation, stochastic

Suppose I have a stationary process $\phi(t)$ with a known autocorrelation function

$$ A(\tau) \equiv \langle \phi(0) \phi(\tau) \rangle$$

and suppose I also know that $\phi(t)$ is Gaussian distributed.

If I have a particular realization of the process in which $\phi(0)=\phi_0$, what is the conditional distribution of $\phi(t)$ for later times in that realization?

Answer (score 1):

"I know that $\phi(t)$ is Gaussian distributed" is not the same as saying
"$\{\phi(t)\}$ is a Gaussian process" but I will assume that the latter is meant. With this assumption, and the additional assumption that the process is
*wide-sense-stationary* (the autocorrelation function is listed as having only one argument), the process is *strictly stationary* and thus
$\phi(t)$ and $\phi(0)$ are *jointly* Gaussian random variables. They have
the same mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and 
their correlation coefficient is $\rho$ where
$$\mu = \sqrt{\lim_{t\to \infty} A(t)}, \qquad \sigma^2 = A(0)-\mu^2,
\qquad \rho(t) = \frac{A(t)-\mu^2}{\sigma^2}.$$
Consequently the *conditional* distribution of $\phi(t)$ given
that $\phi(0)$ has taken on value $\phi_0$ is *Gaussian*
with mean $\mu + \rho(t)(\phi_0 - \mu) = \rho(t) \phi_0 + (1-\rho(t))\mu$
and variance $\sigma^2(1-\rho(t)^2)$. Note that as $t\to\infty$, 
the *conditional* distribution of $\phi(t)$ approaches the
*unconditional* distribution of $\phi(t)$: the distant past affects
the present state less and less.

For more information about Gaussian processes, see, for example,
*[this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/481/235)* to a
different question.

Comment: Could either explain *why* $\rho = (A(t) - \mu^2) / \sigma^2$ or provide a reference?

Comment: $$A(t) = E[\phi(0)\phi(t)] = \operatorname{cov}(\phi(0), \phi(t)) + E[\phi(0)]E[\phi(t)] = \operatorname{cov}(\phi(0), \phi(t))+\mu^2.$$ $$\rho= \frac{\operatorname{cov}(\phi(0), \phi(t))}{\sqrt{\operatorname{var}(\phi(0))\operatorname{var}(\phi(t))}}$$

Comment: This seems related to [Doob's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoobsTheorem.html).