# Properties of Stochastic Processes

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, continuous-signals, stochastic

I have a basic question about stochastic processes:

**When some informations such as wss, uncorraleted sampled, white about random signal (say x[n]) are given, what do we exactly have?**

- ***For example white information:***
  I know if x[n] is white, its power density function $ P_{x}(e^{j\omega}) $ is constant value independent of $ \omega $. I suppose it means autocorrelation function of x[n] consists of dirac? (I am not sure here, If I am wrong, please correct me).
- ***Uncorraleted samples:*** I know if the random signal is uncorrelated, its covariance equals to zero which means its autocorrelation equals to square of its mean. But uncorraleted samples means this, or something else?
- ***What about wss?:*** I know if the signal is wss, mean (average) of x[n] is constant which is useful information when $ x_{c}(t) $ (constinuous time form of x[n]) and its means are given and we can say directly mean of x[n] is the same as mean of $ x_{c}(t) $. Moreover, we have $ \phi_{x}[m]  =  \phi_{x_{c}}[mT] $ where T is the sampling period and $ \mu_{x_{c}}^{2} = \mu_{x}^{2} $ where $ \mu $ is the power of the signals (second moment).

Any correction, addition, comment would be appreciated.

---

Pass through an example may be more convenient:

Suppose we have a system like this:

[image]

where, x[n]: wss, $ \eta_{x} = 0 $ (mean value), uncorrelated samples, $ \sigma_{x}^{2} $ and h[n] are given.

1. How to calculate $ \eta_{y}[m] $ the mean, $ \phi_{y}[m] $ the autocorrelation and $ \mu_{y}[m] $ the average power of y[n]?
2. How to calculate $ \eta_{v}[m] $ the mean, $ \phi_{v}[m] $ the autocorrelation and $ \mu_{v}[m] $ the average power of v[n]?

Comment: There are far too many separate queries lumped into a single question, and any answer will be far too long and detailed: you are essentially asking that people write a whole chapter of a book for your edification.  So, I am voting to close your question as too broad. _Some_ of your questions are answered [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/488/235) and perhaps you can edit your question to something more reasonable after reading and understanding that answer.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, You are right it is a bit broad question, I guess. In fact, I am looking for the information of if x[n] wss, then ...; if x[n] white, then ...; if x[n] uncorrelated samples, then ... I think they are basic properties to solve question. I feel like I can't use these informations and I fail to solve question because of unused infromations.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, this question is rather broad, so here I will just answer your last question about the autocorrelation of the output signal $y[n]$. You might know the following relation concerning the power spectra of input and output sequences:

$$S_y(\omega)=S_x(\omega)|H(\omega)|^2\tag{1}$$

where $H(\omega)$ is the frequency response of the LTI system. From the inverse Fourier transform of (1) you get a corresponding relation between the autocorrelation functions:

$$\phi_y[m]=\phi_x[m]\star h[m]\star h^*[-m]\tag{2}$$

where $h[m]$ is the system's impulse response, and $\star$ denotes convolution.

Comment: And even $(2)$  is shown as the last displayed equation $R_y = h*\tilde{h}*R_X$ in the answer that I had referred the OP to.

Comment: Thank you Matt L. for the equations. At least, can you tell me if my inferences about wss, white and uncorrelated samples are correct?